# Freeing memory in subroutine of recursion in C

Tags: c, malloc, free, mergesort

I would like to ask a question about freeing memory in C. I am implementing the mergeSort function as following:

Merge subroutine:

```
int* merge (int* array_left, unsigned int left_length, int* array_right, unsigned int right_length) {

    unsigned int result_size = right_length + left_length;
    int* result = malloc(result_size*sizeof(int));
    int r = 0; // result index 

    // Iterate through all left and right array elements
    int i = 0;  // left index
    int j = 0;  // right index
    while ( (i < left_length) && (j < right_length) ) {
        if ( *(array_left+i) < *(array_right+j) ) {
            *(result+r) = *(array_left+i);
            i++;
        } else {
            *(result+r) = *(array_right+j);
            j++;
        }
        r++;
    }

    // Fill the remaining elements to the result
    if (i < left_length)
        while (i < left_length) {
            *(result+r) = *(array_left+i);
            r++;
            i++;
        }

    if (j < right_length)
        while (j < right_length) {
            *(result+r) = *(array_right+j);
            r++;
            j++;
        }

    return result;
}
```

MergeSort:

```
   int* mergeSort(int* array, unsigned int length) {
      // Base case
    if (length <= 1)
        return array;

    // Middle element
    unsigned int middle = length / 2;

    int* array_right =  mergeSort(array, middle);
    int* array_left = mergeSort(&array[middle], length-middle);

    // Result is merge from two shorted right and left array
    int* result = merge(array_left, length-middle, array_right, middle);

    return result;
}
```

The program runs correctly but I didn't free memory from my malloc calls and in fact I can't figure it out how to place free(). I tried to free array_right and array_left but I got error telling me I can only free the pointer directly allocated by malloc.

Please help! Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add

```
free(arrayLeft);
free(arrayRight);
```

and also malloc and copy the array even in case its length is one in mergeSort:

```
int* mergeSort(int* array, unsigned int length) {
    // Base case
    if (!length) return NULL;
    if (length == 1) {
        // Make a copy of a single-element array
        int *tmp = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *tmp = *array;
        return tmp;
    }
    ... // The rest of your code
}
```

This would ensure that the caller of mergeSort *always* owns the array that it gets back, and so he must free it in all cases.

The reason it didn't work when you tried it was that you did not make copies of trivial arrays, which resulted in double-freeing some of them.

Comment: Thank you, can you give me more specific code? I don't understand what do you mean by "make copies of trivival arrays" and "caller owns the array that it gets back".

Comment: @HoangNT Sure take a look. By "owning" the array I mean "needs to free".